# Git squash/fixup как чистый коммит

Tags: git, git-rebase

Постоянно делаю git rebase перед тем, как отправить в репозиторий коммиты и вот мне какая штука не очень нравится. Два коммита, которые я объединяю через squash или fixup дважды повторяют в описании автора коммита:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо, первый - это тот, кто сделал первый коммит, а второй - это тот, кто вливает коммит. Ну или может быть автор второго коммита, неважно: это ведь тоже я!

Можно как-то настроить, чтобы подобные совпадения выглядели сразу как чистый коммит? Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я конечно знаю гарантированный способ: ещё раз сделать rebase, отметить коммит через edit, разобрать его обратно и снова собрать, но как-то слишком много действий для такой операции. Хотелось бы, чтобы при совпадении автора делающего rebase с автором объединяемых коммитов история была чище.

Сам пробовал разные настройки у rebase, искал скрипты git filter-branch и пробовал удалять из reflog'а коммиты старее чем минута через git fsck/gc.

Comment: А не всё равно? Вообще-то эти два поля есть всегда, просто когда они совпадают ваш редактор не показывает дубль. В данном случае отличается время.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а) Лишняя информация, только отвлекает. И мелкий перфекционизм опять же. б) описанное поведение во всех git viewer'ах, я не только студией пользуюсь. в) значит, нужно второму коммиту переписать время на такое же - ага, попробую.